# GarbageCollection : can class level member variable or insances reclaimed By GC

Tags: garbage-collection

I Know that Static references variable or instance variable not reclaimed by Garbage Collector but can class level non static variable reclaimed by garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind garbage collection is that memory is references are monitored automatically.

A class instance serves as a reference holder of its member variables so the garbage collector should never collect the members before the instance.